# Change Button text and Background Color when clicked in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I know this question is asked frequently, I have applied many codes but still I'm not getting solution.

I have three radio buttons, when I select `radiobutton1` it shows show buttons, now i want that when the user click `radiobutton1` it shows button, the first button is preselected and if the user wants to select other button from option the button background color and text color should change.

I'm trying some code but only first button color is changed it does not change other buttons colors. My code is:

```
-(void)btnClick:(UIButton *)sender{

    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1:
            if ([rd1 isSelected]==YES ) {

                [rd1 setSelected:YES];
            }
            else{
                [rd1 setSelected:YES];

                [rd2 setSelected:NO];

                [rd3 setSelected:NO];

                _house.hidden=NO;

                _flat.hidden=NO;

                _upperP.hidden=NO;

                _lowerP.hidden=NO;

                _farmH.hidden=NO;

                _roomB.hidden=NO;

                _pentH.hidden=NO;

                _resident.hidden=YES;

                _commercial.hidden=YES;

                _agricult.hidden=YES;


                _industry.hidden=YES;

                _plot.hidden=YES;

                _plotF.hidden=YES;

                _office.hidden=YES;

                _shop.hidden=YES;

                _wareH.hidden=YES;

                _factory.hidden=YES;

                _building.hidden=YES;

                _other.hidden=YES;

                if ([_house isSelected]==YES) {

                    House=_house.titleLabel.text;

                    NSLog(@"Button is %@",House);

                    _flat.enabled=NO;

                    _upperP.enabled=NO;

                    _lowerP.enabled=NO;

                    _farmH.enabled=NO;

                    _roomB.enabled=NO;

                    _pentH.enabled=NO;

                }

                else if ([_flat isSelected]==YES) {

                    _house.enabled=NO;

                    _upperP.enabled=NO;

                    _lowerP.enabled=NO;

                    _farmH.enabled=NO;

                    _roomB.enabled=NO;

                    _pentH.enabled=NO;


                }

                [self BgColor];


            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if ([rd2 isSelected]==YES ) {

                [rd2 setSelected:NO];
            }
            else{
                [rd2 setSelected:YES];

                [rd1 setSelected:NO];

                [rd3 setSelected:NO];

                _resident.hidden=NO;

                _commercial.hidden=NO;

                _agricult.hidden=NO;

                _industry.hidden=NO;

                _plot.hidden=NO;

                _plotF.hidden=NO;

                _house.hidden=YES;

                _flat.hidden=YES;

                _upperP.hidden=YES;

                _lowerP.hidden=YES;

                _farmH.hidden=YES;

                _roomB.hidden=YES;

                _pentH.hidden=YES;

                _shop.hidden=YES;

                _wareH.hidden=YES;

                _factory.hidden=YES;

                _building.hidden=YES;


                _other.hidden=YES;

                _office.hidden=YES;




            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if ([rd3 isSelected]==YES ) {

                [rd3 setSelected:NO];
            }
            else{
                [rd3 setSelected:YES];

                [rd2 setSelected:NO];

                [rd1 setSelected:NO];

                _office.hidden=NO;

                _shop.hidden=NO;

                _wareH.hidden=NO;

                _factory.hidden=NO;

                _building.hidden=NO;

                _other.hidden=NO;

                _house.hidden=YES;

                _flat.hidden=YES;

                _upperP.hidden=YES;

                _lowerP.hidden=YES;

                _farmH.hidden=YES;

                _roomB.hidden=YES;

                _pentH.hidden=YES;
                _resident.hidden=YES;

                _commercial.hidden=YES;

                _agricult.hidden=YES;

                _industry.hidden=YES;

                _plot.hidden=YES;

                _plotF.hidden=YES;

            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

-(void)BgColor{

    if ([_house isSelected]==YES) {

        [_house setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        _house.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    }
    else if (([_flat isSelected]==YES)){

        [_flat setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        _flat.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem could be that you call `[self BgColor];` only inside the `case 1:` block. Since that method seems to take care of the title and background color for house and flat, maybe you should always call it (after the `switch` statement).

If that doesn't work, my advice is to break the problem in smaller pieces. For example, create 3 IBActions, one for each button. Give outlet names to each one of the buttons so that you know exactly what you're changing every time. Try to move repeating code to its own method. Test all the time and in small steps until you make it!

To get you started, [here's a sample project](https://github.com/phi161/ButtonTester) that has some basic similar functionality.

Comment: Actually the buttons shown after selecting radiobutton1 there is also no change in colors is coming. @phi

Comment: Can you share a project with a minimal example of what you're trying to do? Or at least some screenshots?

Comment: i have added screen shot check it out. In screenshot there is a radio button having some buttons under it i want them to change background and text color when click. @phi

Comment: I can only help you by showing some sample code, check my updated answer

Comment: Yup, i got the answer from the link of project u provided, thanks man :) . @phi

Answer (score 0):

I think for radio button, you just need to set Image for all for. So you just have to make a button to selected/normal state.

You can set image for all different state like this:

```
[YOUR_BUTTON setImage:YOUR_IMAGE_NORMAL forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[YOUR_BUTTON setImage:YOUR_IMAGE_SELECTED forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[YOUR_BUTTON setImage:YOUR_IMAGE_HEIGHLIGHED forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[YOUR_BUTTON setImage:YOUR_IMAGE_DISABLE forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

About the text color, let me give you one small trick for it. Check my below method:

```
-(void)btnClick:(UIButton *)sender{
     // This is button on which user is clicked
    UIButton *btnCurrent = (UIButton *)sender;

    if(btnReference != nil)
    {
        // If this is not a nil, it means you have clicked another button previously.
        // So make it normal before doing any thing.
        btnReference.selected = false;
        [btnReference setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Assign reference of current button
        btnReference = btnCurrent;
    }

    // Make changes for clicked button
    btnReference.selected = TRUE;
    [btnReference setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btnReference setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Put this condition on top of your method. So you don't have to worry about color and all.